# unable to connect rabbitmq server on remote machine (windows server)

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, rabbitmq.client

I'm using RabbitMq server 3.9.4 and OTP 24 on Windows Server 2019 and want to connect remote host.

in the rabbitmq i created user with those settings:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user rmq password
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / rmq ".*" ".*" ".*"
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags rmq administrator

and opened port 5672 in the firewall for remote access.
```

I'm trying to connect my .net rabbitmq client from other machine but connection refused.

```
 var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = "myhostname",
                UserName = "rmq",
                Password = "password",
            };                                                                              
var connection = factory.CreateConnection()
```

Comment: Can you add the error message? Are you sure network access is ok (try something like `nc -zv <rabbitmq host> 5672` from the host running the JS code)? Is your rabbitmq node OK (try `rabbitmqctl status`)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @DavidL! network is OK and in localhost it's OK. error running server in remote machine: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: rabbitmqctl status: 

[1mFile Descriptors[0m

Total: 2, limit: 65439
Sockets: 0, limit: 58893

[1mFree Disk Space[0m

Low free disk space watermark: 0.05 gb
Free disk space: 139.6832 gb

[1mTotals[0m

Connection count: 0
Queue count: 0
Virtual host count: 1

[1mListeners[0m

Interface: [::], port: 25672, protocol: clustering, purpose: inter-node and CLI tool communication
Interface: [::], port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0
Interface: 0.0.0.0, port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0